# Print all elements of 1d array in formated string

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on 1D-arrays of variable length in python and trying to print them in a formated string in a comfortable way.

Example array:

`numbers = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`

Desired output:

`"The numbers are 1.0, 2.0, 3.0"`

I can't get any further than this solution which requires me to adjust the print statement with the length of the numbers array.

```
print("The numbers are " + "%.1f, " *len(numbers) %(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join your formatted numbers.

```py
print('The numbers are ' + ', '.join('%.1f' % n for n in numbers))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```py
"The numbers are " + ", ".join([f"{n:.1f}" for n in numbers])
```

(f-strings are python 3.6+, modify the syntax in the list comprehension if you need to support an older version)